# ScrollBar in Classes in Tkinter Python

Tags: tkinter, scrollbars

```
class CreatingWindowForEachLesson():
    def __init__(self,root,t,d1,d2,d3):
        self.t=t
        self.root=root
        self.root.focus_set()
        self.root.title(self.t)
        self.lesson=BooleanVar()
        self.l=Label(self.root,text=self.t,bg='blue') #ΤΟΜΕΑΣ ΣΠΟΥΔΑΣΤΗ 
        self.l.pack()
        self.frame1=Frame(self.root) #ΤΙΤΛΟΣ ΜΑΘΗΜΑΤΟΣ
        self.frame1.pack(anchor="center",side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.frame=Frame.__init__(self)
        self.canvas =Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        Frame.__init__(self,self.canvas)
        Label(self,text="FirstColBot",width=30).grid(row=0,column=0)            
        Label(self,text="SecndColBot",width=20).grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(root, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
        self.vsb = Scrollbar(root, orient="vertical", command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self.frame)
        self.canvas.create_window((4,4), window=self)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.OnFrameConfigure)
```

I'm trying to put some scrollbars for my window root so as to print some lists of lessons. I 've read some related posts in stackoverflow and found some lines of code, but probably I'm doing sth wrong and cannot adjust them to my code. Any ideas, any help? I'm new to Python so please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listbox will possibly work better than a canvas. Effbot's scrollbar and listbox example http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm